# when are objects created in c++?

Tags: c++

If the program execution in c++ starts in main function, when will the programming class's object be generated during execution?

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class programming
{
   private:
      int variable;

   public:

      void input_value()
      {
         cout << "In function input_value, Enter an integer\n";
         cin >> variable;
      }

      void output_value()
      {
         cout << "Variable entered is ";
         cout << variable << "\n";
      }
};

programming object;

main()
{

   object.input_value();
   object.output_value();

   return 0;
}
```

can anybody help?

Comment: If you do as a pointer it is created when you do a new operation. If you create without a pointer it is created on the stack when the program is initialized.

Comment: object is likely not on the stack.

Comment: @demonofnight you mean before starting main()?

Comment: Another thing is whe you create a variable without a pointer it is deleted on the end of the scope, when you close the scope { programming obj; .... } // now it deletes

Comment: @Aparan, no, it is created when the program is loaded to the ram (in this specific scenario)

Comment: @Aparan The rules are not stupid. You will come to know they are worth enough with you come across various issues when you do answering.

Comment: I suggest reading this Meta post on ["What can I do when getting 'It does not meet our quality standards'?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards). Please don't add garbage lines to your post

Comment: @EAGER_STUDENT: why is this particular rule not stupid?( I m saying about the need for some blah blah after saying your problem giving the code sample). I had stated the problem in first line and then provided the code. Still it asks me to give more details

Comment: @Aparan It is not a standard rule that `every time you have to give sample code`. Its depend on situation & need. Moreover you many not be lazy in explaining you problem, when some one volunteers to answer and ask for more details only to explain more clearer. And to the fun part "Still it asks me to give more details" - We are not bots though.

Comment: @EAGER_STUDENT So the rule is to add  something before and after the code section. Hmm.. got it. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `object` is a static (i.e. global) variable, its constructor is executed when the global constructors are run, i.e. before `main()` starts executing.

Comment: It's not static, it's just global; static means something subtly different in case of non-members.

Comment: It does have `static storage duration`, though.

Answer (score 3):

It is created before `main` starts. In C++, some "program execution" can occur before `main`.

Answer (score 1):

YOUR program starts with your code in main, but "things" happen before that. Some compilers/environments will add some extra code just at the beginning of main to create global objects, in other cases, the creation of global is code that runs just before main. All you need to really care about is that "it happens before any of your code".

However, you can't rely on global objects being initialized before some OTHER global objects....

Comment: You can rely on global objects in the **same** translation unit being initialized in order of their definitions.

Comment: Thanks Pete, I wasn't sure exactly what the rules were, but I knew there is enough vagueness to not rely on some particular order.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, global objects are created as static data before main is called.  This means that memory is allocated on neither the stack nor the heap, but instead is placed in memory in a data segment.  A data segment is an area of memory laid out in a manner similar to how a program's execution code is stored.  The memory is allocated when the program is loaded into memory before any code runs.

C++ does not require that global objects be created in any particular order.  The only guarantee is that they will be created before `main` is called.  That is, assume global constructors are called essentially at random.